# Bayes theorem to find probability of coin toss

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-theorem, bayes-theorem

I toss a coin 6 times and get a total of four heads (H). What is the probability my first roll was heads?

My thinking:

Let B be the event of 4H out of 6 tosses. I do this by binomial.

$P(B) = \left(\frac{1}{64}\binom{6}{4}\right) = \frac{15}{64}$

Let A be the event the first toss is H. I originally thought this be $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ however I was looking through my notes at a similar question and I believe

$P(A) = \left(\frac{1}{64}\binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{4} +\binom{5}{5}\right) = \frac{16}{64}$

Thus by bayes theorem: $$ P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A) \, P(A)}{P(B)} $$

where ${P(B \mid A) \, P(A)}$ = $P(A \cap B)$

$P(A \mid B) =\frac{15}{16}$

The answer in the book is $\frac{2}{3}$ so clearly my answer is wrong. Any guidance as to why I did not get $\frac{2}{3}$ for the probability the first role is a head? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your computation for $B$.  You are told that you have a "total of four Heads", so you should not have the terms $\binom 65, \binom 66$.  Same for your computation of $A$.

Comment: I have edited it, however it does still not give me the correct answer

Comment: As I say, you make the same mistake in your computation of $A$.